# How to use ContextWrapper to create a cursor and find files in Android Directory?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-cursor

I created a simplified activity to ilustrate my problem. I am trying to create a cursor that goes through the files in my app's root directory, however  `resolver.query(...)` returns null and the program returns on this line.

```
class TestingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testing)
        testCursor()
    }

    fun testCursor() {

        val resolver = contentResolver
        val path = Uri.parse(Environment.getRootDirectory().absolutePath)

        val cursor = resolver.query(path, null, null, null, null) ?: return
        if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.close()
            return
        }

        do {
            //do something with cursor
        } while (cursor.moveToNext())
        cursor.close()
    }
}
```

I have all my permissions set in my manifest file, I just cannot create a proper cursor, what should I do to make this work?